# How do I transmit over the serial port asynchronously in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am writing a program to simulate a device that transmits data over the serial port. To do this, I created a System.IO.Ports.SerialPort object in my form, and a System.Windows.Forms.Timer to do the transmitting at a given frequency. Everything works fine except that as the frequency approaches the limit of the serial port speed, it starts to lock up the UI and eventually becomes unresponsive when the data is being sent for transmission faster than the port data speed. My code is:

```
private void OnSendTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder("$", 51);
    //code to build the first output string
    SendingPort.WriteLine(outputString.ToString());
    outputString = new StringBuilder("$", 44);
    //code to build the second output string
    SendingPort.WriteLine(outputString.ToString());

    if (SendingPort.BytesToWrite > 100)
    {
        OnStartStopClicked(sender, e);
        MessageBox.Show("Warning: Sending buffer is overflowing!");
    }
}
```

I was expecting the WriteLine function to be asynchronous - return immediately while the port transmits in the background. Instead, it seems that the OnSendTimerTick function is properly threaded, but WriteLine seems to be running in the UI thread.

How can I get the serial port to behave in this way? Creating the SerialPort object in the timer seems like a bad idea, because then I'd have to open and close it on each timer tick.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in the question, but the device being simulated simply sends out an update of several parameters at a given frequency continuously. A queue doesn't make sense because if the transmit rate is faster than the port rate, it would just grow endlessly. That's why I put in that attempt to check the buffer size - if the buffer grows at all, then the rate is too fast and the transmitter should throw an error and stop.

Answer (score 2):

It is only partly asynchronous, it will immediately return but only as long as the bytes you write will fit in the serial port driver's transmit buffer.  That's going to come to a screeching stop when you flood the port with too much data, faster than it can transmit.  You can make it truly asynchronous by using the SerialPort.BaseStream.BeginWrite() method.  That doesn't make it any faster but moves the bottleneck somewhere else, possibly away from the UI.

Comment: That makes sense, but if that's how it works, then why doesn't it detect that the buffer is filling faster than it can transmit when I check SendingPort.BytesToWrite?

Comment: Because you check it *after* writing instead of before?  Not so sure, drivers for USB emulators tend to be flaky, in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This could be resolved(slowness of the UI) if you created a Queue of strings to be written and had a background thread that wrote to the serial port from the queue.  If you take that approach be careful of the size of the queue.

edit:  For some reason I can't use Add Comment, so I'll just edit this.  The documentation for BeginWrite has this statement "The default implementation of BeginWrite on a stream calls the Write method synchronously, which means that Write might block on some streams."  It then goes on to exclude File and Network streams, but not SerialPort.  I guess you can try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, the timer event handler is being executed on the UI thread. Same is true if you're using `System.Timers.Timer` when the `SynchronizingObject` is set to the form. If the serial port buffer fills up, the thread has to wait until it has enough space to hold the new data that you want to send.

I would suggest that you use a `System.Threading.Timer` to do this. The timer callback is called on a pool thread, meaning that the UI thread won't lock up if the `WriteLine` has to wait. If you do this, then you have to make sure that there is only one threading executing the timer callback at any time. Otherwise you can get data out of order. The best way to do that would be to make the timer a one-shot and re-initialize it at the end of every callback:

```
const int TimerFrequency = 50;  // or whatever
System.Threading.Timer timer;

void InitTimer()
{
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, TimerFrequency, Timeout.Infinite);
}

void TimerCallback(object state)
{
    // do your stuff here
    // Now reset the timer
    timer.Change(TimerFrequency, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Passing a valid of `Timeout.Infinite` as the `period` parameter prevents the timer from being a periodic timer. Instead, it fires just once. The `Timer.Change` re-initializes the timer after each send.

A possibly better way to handle this is to eliminate the timer altogether by setting the `WriteBufferSize` to a sufficiently large value. Then your program can just dump all of its data into the buffer and let the `SerialPort` instance worry about dribbling it out across the wire. This assumes, of course, that you can create a buffer large enough to hold whatever your program is trying to send.